# Using stix2 with amsart and not running out of math alphabets

Tags: fonts, pdftex, stix

I generally typeset my documents using lualatex or xelatex but many math journals seem to default to pdflatex and I'd like to use the stix2 package to use those nice fonts.  Unfortunately, I also need to use mathrsfs to get a seperate script font (under unicode-math for lua/xe latex I just use the alternate stylistic set but haven't seen any way to do this with stix2 under pdflatex) and when I combine this with a brush script (defined with \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbrush}{T1}{pbsi}{xl}{n}) as well as the fix to corner quotes that makes them look nice stolen from another answer on this site I run out of math alphabets.  Is there a way to fix this without just giving up on the nicer corner quotes?

I've provided a minimal example illustrating the problem below:

```
% \documentclass[leqno]{amsart}
\documentclass{amsart}



    \usepackage[lcgreekalpha]{stix2}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs} 
    \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbrush}{T1}{pbsi}{xl}{n}



\makeatletter

% \usepackage{rec-thy}
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{MnLargeSymbols}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}
    \SetSymbolFont{MnLargeSymbols}{bold}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}
    \DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
        <-6>  MnSymbolE5
       <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
       <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
       <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
       <9-10> MnSymbolE9
      <10-12> MnSymbolE10
      <12->   MnSymbolE12
    }{}
    \DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
        <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
       <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
       <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
       <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
       <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
      <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
      <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12
    }{}
    \DeclareMathDelimiter{\@recthy@ulcorner}
        {\mathopen}{MnLargeSymbols}{'036}{MnLargeSymbols}{'036}
    \DeclareMathDelimiter{\@recthy@urcorner}
        {\mathclose}{MnLargeSymbols}{'043}{MnLargeSymbols}{'043}
        \let\ulcorner=\@recthy@ulcorner
        \let\urcorner=\@recthy@urcorner
         \newcommand*{\godelnum}[1]{\left\ulcorner #1 \right\urcorner}

\begin{document}

\(\mathbrush{b} \)  



\end{document}
```

Comment: You ask about `stix2` and show `MnSymbol`. And no, `amsart` doesn't load amssymb. A single math alphabet can be easily emulated without allocating a math group. Please, complete to a full example showing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that.

Comment: the stix(2)  packages offer \mathcal and \mathscr  do you need mathrsfs as well?

Comment: It does?  How do I activate that?  I know how to do that using unicode-math I need to use the other stylistic set…or is this just by default using stix2?

Comment: you don't have to do anything: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{stix2}\begin{document}$ABC\mathscr{ABC}\mathcal{ABC}$\end{document}`

Comment: Ok, thanks that's the answer I most needed!

Comment: `texdoc stix2`  section 4 lists all the available alphabets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It runs without error with

```
\documentclass[noamsfonts]{amsart}
```

Comment: Ohh, ok that's what I'm missing.  I presume I can load iftex via \RequirePackage before setting the documentclass so I can enable this to compile on both.

Comment: @PeterGerdes why test?

Comment: Because I was pretty sure it would in some sense work but not sure if this was bad practice (I don't really understand the difference between RequirePackage and usepackage) and figured you would correct me if I was wrong and if you didn't want to bother to reply you wouldn't.  Besides, if I asked and was correct and someone else didn't know then it would help them find out.

Comment: @PeterGerdes  sorry I don't understand what you mean at all. you can use `\documentclass[noamsfonts]{amsart}` with pdflatex or xelatex or lualatex so why do you need an iftex test? what do you want to do differently in each case?